# UILabel size adjustment within a UITableViewCell loaded from Nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

UILabel within in a Cell contains a NSLocalizedString; varying from a few characters to a paragraph depending on language. The frame of the UILabel sometime does, and sometimes doesn't draw to fit the string length. I believe this is an issue with reuse, but I'm at a loss on how to fix it.

I have a series of five different UITableViewCell subclasses loaded from Nibs (project requirement) in `viewDidLoad`:

```
UINib *Cell1Nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCell1" bundle:nil];
[[self tableView] registerNib:Cell1Nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"custCell1"];

UINib *Cell2Nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"customCell2" bundle:nil];
[[self tableView] registerNib:Cell2Nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"custCell2"];
//etc.
```

I have a helper for getting height of the UILabel depending on the text used:

```
- (CGFloat)getTextHeight:(NSString *)locStr forLabelWidth:(CGFloat)w {
    UILabel  *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, 110)];
    label.numberOfLines=0;
    label.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
    label.text = locStr; // highly variable & already localized
    label.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody]; 
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(w, CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize requiredSize = [label sizeThatFits:maxSize];
    label = nil; // ARC paranoia
    return requiredSize.height;
}
```

In `heightForRowAtIndexPath` I call `getTextHeight:forLabelWidth:`, using it to determin the cell height and storing the result into an NSMutableArray called, `labelHeightforRow.` So far, everything works great.

I create the table as such:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    DLX_CellDescriptor *desc = [[DLX_CellDescriptor alloc] initWithRow:indexPath.row];
    //DLX_CellDescriptor describes attributes for cell at index , essentially a list of strings
    CGFloat helpTextHeight = [[labelHeightforRow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue];

    if ([desc.nibToUse caseInsensitiveCompare:@"custCell1"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
        DLX_CustCell1 *currCell = (DLX_CustCell1 *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"custCell1"];
        CGPoint origin = currCell.theLabel.frame.origin;
        CGFloat w = currCell.theLabel.frame.size.width;
        currCell.theLabel.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, w, helpTextHeight);
        currCell.theLabel.text = desc.localizedText;
        currCell.theLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
        currCell.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell = currCell;
    } else if ([desc.nibToUse caseInsensitiveCompare:@"custCell2"] == NSOrderedSame ) {
        DLX_CustCell2 *currCell = (DLX_CustCell2 *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"custCell2"];
        CGPoint origin = currCell.theLabel.frame.origin;
        CGFloat w = currCell.theLabel.frame.size.width;
        currCell.theLabel.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, w, helpTextHeight);
        currCell.theLabel.text = desc.localizedText;
        currCell.theLabel.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
        currCell.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell = currCell;
    } // for about 26 rows of 5 different non-identical sytles
      // simplified in this example
    return cell;
}
```

This issue is that when the initial TableView is created, the UILabel is the height specified in the Nib: truncating extra long text and giving a large white space below (from the correct cell height adjustment). When the table is redrawn, the UILabel turns into the correct height specified in the code; showing the entire string. Then, if the cell is recreated; say, after it has scrolled off the screen and another of it's cell type has drawn, the long-text label is using the truncating height from the Nib again.

I tried putting `layoutSubviews` into the custom UITableViewCell (customCell1.m, for example) as such:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    NSInteger currCell = self.tag;
    DLX_CellDescriptor *desc = [[DLX_CellDescriptor alloc] initWithRow:currCell];
    CGPoint origin = theLabel.frame.origin;
    CGSize size = theLabel.frame.size;
    CGFloat textHeight = [self getTextHeight:desc.localizedText forLabelWidth:size.width];
    theLabel.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, size.width, textHeight);
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

But that had the effect of immutably ensuring that the height from the Nib was used; even though upon inspection, `textheight` was correct (and, for some languages, much larger then the Nib's height.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that your cell is relatively simple, one easy way to solve your problem is don't use reuse. Just load the nib file from bundle. Delete those `registerNib` related code. And do it like this:

```
NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"DistrictCellReuseIdentifier";
DistrictCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DistrictCell" owner:self options:nil][0];
}
```

Comment: I drastically simplified the example code I provided in the question to keep from cluttering up the question. The actual cells have UIControls, images, backgrounds, accordion functionality, etc. However, I am not familiar with turning off reuse. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: The suggested code, if implemented as typed, resulted in the a different way to get the same error. However, it did point me towards the correct path. What I believe fixed the reuse issue was making sure the reuseIdentifier was unique like `NSString *reuseIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellReuseIdentifier%d",indexPath.row];`

Comment: @NSConfusedCoder Oh sorry I forget the NO reuse! And yes, your way is correct.